# How can I open an FLP file?

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

I would like to make some modifications to the open-source plugin: `WordPress Audio Player` but I don't know how to open the FLP file (or project). You can see the project [here](http://wpaudioplayer.com/source/).

I have tried with `Adobe Flash Professional CS6` but it says something like: `Unexpected end of file`. Also I have tried with `FlashDevelop` but it says: `The selected file was not a valid Flash Builder project`.

The mentioned `FLP` file you can find it [here](http://trac.assembla.com/1pixelout/browser/audio-player/trunk/source).

The full project you can find it [here](http://trac.assembla.com/1pixelout/browser/audio-player).

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the `FLP` (Flash Project) file because it's no longer in use with Flash PRO (since CS4 I think).

So, to load your project, in your Flash PRO CS6, press <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**F8**</kbd> ( or **Window** > **Project** ), the **PROJECT** panel will be opened, then you have just to open the project ( from the menu **Projects** ) by going to the directory containing the `FLP` file :

[image]

Then

[image]

Deselect **Create default document** because we will select the `player.fla` file, which is provided with the project, using a right click and **Make Default Document**

[image]

That's all !

If you still have problems, you can take a look on [this document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7effa.html) by Adobe about working with Flash projects.

You can also download the project from [here](https://mega.nz/#!XgRHAYJD!22sYyZWeLoU8GHaADmJuJOF8hI2uEaNXYLjMFrzQ3BA).

---

You can also avoid all that by just editing the classes that you want and then compile the `player.fla` file ;)

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

First, Download FL Studio (you must buy a license) And next install it. Last, open flp file Done Easy