# external swf no longer loading in modern browsers - security issue?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Years ago, I created a swf that upon init, loads an external swf. It worked reliably for years.  Now, it's been brought back, but no longer loads the swf in more modern browsers, like in its heyday.  It now fails in Chrome 57 and IE11, but worked around IE8 and Chrome 20ish.  I'm thinking this might be a security issue.  I tried setting compatibility mode in IE but that didn't help.  Am I missing a security setting somewhere?

Comment: Apart from checking for crossdomain XML issues... Has the second external swf always been loaded from an `https` location? That's a common expectation now (especially Firefox was first but haven't checked with other browsers since don't need such feature much). If your swf's `URLRequest` code didn't include `https://` in there that might be the issue. To be fair not enough information to help you.. It depends how you load (`Loader` vs `URLStream`) and where you load from (`http` vs `https`) etc.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  It's designed to run locally as a presentation.  It's not online.  I thought about crossdomain xml, but have never run into any issues with that ever.

Comment: Crossdomain only matters between servers. If its not accessing the internet from hard drive then it cannot be any security issue... That said why involve browsers? I mean just use the standalone Flash Player (see this other [**Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41989416/2057709) for any useful hints). Since you may not want to have users drag swfs to player windows, consider making a batch file  eg: called `Start.bat` with code to auto-open the SWF. The standalone Player works like the older NPapi Flash plugin (modern use the Google/Adobe's newer PPapi Player) so standalone may work best...

Comment: That's a good idea.  It actually leads me to another problem though: re-publishing as an exe from Animate, something I have no experience with.  I have yet to figure out how it would read my old .flp (flash project file) to connect the packages I used to compile five years ago.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I've not worked with .flp so only used .fla. Does this [**Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33401726/2057709) make sense to you about conversion options etc? Are you now wanting to instead export a **projector** (swf and player contained as one exe file)? That seems like best solution since you have sources.

Comment: That was a good attempt at a relevant answer, but I don't think it applies to my situation.  Making a projector certainly seems more reliable.  The .flp was an xml directory pointing to all of the .as files.  I haven't figured out how to load them all in to Animate, like the old Flash publish settings.

Comment: I compiled into an exe and that seemed to do the trick.  I also figured out including packages in Animate.  It's been a while, so I was rusty.  If you put exe as an answer, I'll mark it correct.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Plus-1 for solving it before an answer was posted. Glad it's worked out okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crossdomain only matters between servers. If its not accessing the internet from hard drive then it cannot be any security issue...

Since it will run offline why involve browsers?

- Just use the standalone Flash Player (see this other [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949210/swf-file-not-launching-in-chrome/41989416#41989416) for any useful hints).
- If you have original source codes then just compile output as **.exe** instead of an **.swf**.